# Mysql ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Tags: mysql

When I try to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `oro_workflow_restriction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `workflow_step_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workflow_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `attribute` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `entity_class` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mode_values` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci COMMENT '(DC2Type:json_array)',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `oro_workflow_restriction_idx` (`workflow_name`,`workflow_step_id`,`field`,`entity_class`,`mode`),
  KEY `IDX_3D2C17E271FE882C` (`workflow_step_id`),
  KEY `IDX_3D2C17E21BBC6E3D` (`workflow_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_3D2C17E21BBC6E3D` FOREIGN KEY (`workflow_name`) REFERENCES `oro_workflow_definition` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_3D2C17E271FE882C` FOREIGN KEY (`workflow_step_id`) REFERENCES `oro_workflow_step` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I got an error about Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes.

<s>I don't see why would I get the error. The longest key length is the unique key: 4 + 4 * 255*3 = 3071 bytes < 3072 bytes. (if my calculation is correct)</s>

Clearly `utf8mb4` is 4 bytes per character, I can have only `varchar(191)` at maximum. In my case it is 4 + 4 * 255*4 = 4084 bytes > 3072 bytes.

Is there a way that doesn't require to change the data type to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions

**By Dropping the Unique Constraint**

If you can drop the unique constraint. Enable full-text indexing for search purposes, but you won't be able to enforce unique constraints.

**By Normalizing the Schema**

Put the `varchar(255)` columns out of this table and store `ids` from referred tables. These will be integers. And with integers, composite keys will work just fine.

I think MySQL has done a good job limiting this to 3072 bytes. Otherwise, people would create all kinds of useless indexes that would lead to a performance bottleneck.

Comment: You are right. As you can see the OroCRM is using `name` as the reference of the foreign key which isn't good. Changing the keys will ends up something that we might not able to support the newer version of OroCRM. I guess I have to turn it back to `uft8` instead of `utf8mb4`. That means the system won't able to support some special characters.

Answer (score 1):

The charset is important.

Specifiyng `VARCHAR(1000)` when having column charset `UTF` or alike means that the effective field size is 4 times bigger, as `UTF` characters are in size of 4 bytes.

The allowed index field size is 3072, thus `VARCHAR(1000)` of `UTF` charset means effective size of 4 x 1000 = 4000 bytes.