# Not able to increase size of a particular column in table of mysql. Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Tags: mysql

**My MySQL Version is 8.0.34 CE (64 bits)**

And my table is as below

```
CREATE TABLE `t_report_subscriptions` (
  `subscr_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_header_id` varchar(700) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `update_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_system_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subscr_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq_reportSubsriptions` (`report_header_id`,`user_id`,`source_system_id`),
  KEY `report_id_fk_idx` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_report_id` FOREIGN KEY (`report_header_id`, `source_system_id`) REFERENCES `l_report_header_data` (`REPORT_HEADER_ID`, `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

I am trying to increase the length of the 'user_id' column from 45 to 256 as follows

```
alter table t_report_subscriptions modify column user_id varchar(256) NOT NULL;
```

And getting the following error

```
Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes
```

I tried dropping all the constraints and index of the table then increase the size of the column and then re-creating the constraints and index, but still it does not work

I have dropped the constraints and index as below

```
ALTER TABLE t_report_subscriptions drop index `report_id_fk_idx`;
ALTER TABLE t_report_subscriptions drop index `uq_reportSubsriptions`;
ALTER TABLE t_report_subscriptions DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_report_id;
```

Then increased the length of the 'user_id' column as below

```
alter table t_report_subscriptions modify column user_id varchar(256) NOT NULL;
```

Then re-creating the constraints and index as below

```
ALTER TABLE t_report_subscriptions ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_report_id` FOREIGN KEY (`report_header_id`, `source_system_id`) REFERENCES `l_report_header_data` (`REPORT_HEADER_ID`, `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID`);
ALTER TABLE t_report_subscriptions add index `report_id_fk_idx` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`);
```

But when i try to re-create the unique constraint as below i get the following error

```
ALTER TABLE t_report_subscriptions ADD CONSTRAINT `uq_reportSubsriptions` UNIQUE(`report_header_id`,`user_id`,`source_system_id`);
```

The error is

```
16:12:43    ALTER TABLE t_report_subscriptions ADD CONSTRAINT `uq_reportSubsriptions` UNIQUE(`report_header_id`,`user_id`,`source_system_id`)   Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes  0.000 sec
```

I have referred multiple links

[why this error occur #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609292/why-this-error-occur-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000)

[Mysql ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840560/mysql-error-1071-42000-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-3072-byt)

[MySQL Error #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/mysql-error-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes)

But not able to increase the size of the column.
Any suggestions/help

Comment: What is the maximum length for report_header_id, can you reduce it to something smaller than varchar(700) ?

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini 
The length of report_header_id cannot be reduced. Is there any other option

Comment: Then you need to replace one of the columns in the unique index. You may consider adding a generated column with some kind of hashed value for either user_id or report_header_id. There is of course always a risk of collision so you have to choose the hashed value visely

Answer (score 0):

Not questioning if you actually need an id with 700 chars, you probably don't need to use unicode for it, as it reserves 4 bytes per character in the key.

If you can use e.g. latin1, you only need 1 byte per character, so you can have e.g. a `varchar(2812)`, `varchar(256)` and `int` (4 bytes) for a total of 3072 bytes.

So try e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE `t_report_subscriptions` (
  `subscr_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_header_id` varchar(700) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(256) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `update_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_system_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subscr_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uq_reportSubsriptions` (`report_header_id`,`user_id`,`source_system_id`),
  KEY `report_id_fk_idx` (`report_header_id`,`source_system_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_report_id` FOREIGN KEY (`report_header_id`, `source_system_id`) REFERENCES `l_report_header_data` (`REPORT_HEADER_ID`, `SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

If it is used in a foreign key, you have to change it in the other table too.

If you indeed need unicode, `utf8mb3_general_ci` with 3 bytes per character will probably still be enough for what you want to store in an id.

Comment: This is how the report_header_id looks like D872E5D5-4855-4350-A873-4594121D8E1A . We dont generate the report_header_id, we get it from a source system and we store it in our database.

Comment: That looks like a standard uuid. You said in a comment that you need varchar(700) and cannot make is shorter. A uuid (or rather the string representation) will always have 36 characters, you don't need more (so just making it varchar(36) would be an even simpler solution than changing from unicode. Nevertheless, uuids don't require unicode columns, so e.g. latin1 would work too)

Comment: Just a question to understand. As per my table the charset is CHARSET=utf8mb4. Is that each character takes 4 bytes. Meaning my `report_header_id` is varchar(700) and it takes 700*4 = 2800 bytes. Please help me understand

Comment: With a varchar, it *can* take up to 2800 bytes (if you put 700 bytes with full 4 byte unicodes in it). MySQL only stores the characters used (e.g. if the string has length 36, it only uses bytes for those 36), and also unicode is encoded in a way that the first 128 most common characters (e.g. english letters and numbers) use only 1 byte, so your uuid will (on disk and memory) not need 4 bytes per char. Still, the key needs to be able to store 4*700 bytes cause you *could* store such a maximum unicode string. And MySQL just has a limitation on that maximum key length.